# Date and Time picker as custom editor in Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

How do I create a custom date and time picker editor instead of just a date picker editor?

I have made a date and time picker from jquery-ui library with a jquery-ui-timepicker add-on independently, but i cannot get this to work with tabulator custom editor.

Any help would be great. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabulator's documentation includes a [guide to making custom editors](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/edit#edit-custom)

Essentially the important bits are that it needs to return a DOM Node, that is should call the 'success' function when a value has been set and 'cancel' if the value hasn't changed.

In the case of a jquery UI widget then you also need to make sure you instantiate the widget inside the `onRendered` callback which is triggered when the element is added to the DOM otherwise jQuery will error.

As a basic example based on the built in input editor:

```js
var dateFormatter = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){
    var cellValue = cell.getValue(),
    var input = document.createElement("input"); // define input element
    
    //assign current cell value to input element
    input.value = typeof cellValue !== "undefined" ? cellValue : "";

    //handle loss of focus to the input element and changes in value
    function onChange(e){
        if(((cellValue === null || typeof cellValue === "undefined") && input.value !== "") || input.value !== cellValue){
            success(input.value); //if value has changed save value 
        }else{
            cancel(); //otherwise cancel edit
        }
    }
    
    //submit new value on blur or change
    input.addEventListener("change", onChange);
    input.addEventListener("blur", onChange);

    //instantiate the jQuery widget
    onRendered(function(){
        $(input).datepicker({
            //date picker setup options
        });
    });

    //return input element
    return input;
}
```

*(Using the blur event may cause issues if you have to click in controls for the jQuery widget so you may want to comment out the blur event listener)*

*(Also the change event may not be what you need depending on the usage case but i believe the jquery datepicker widget has an `onSelect` callback that you could use to trigger the success function)*

You would then need to attach the formatter to the column in its column definition:

```js
{title:"Date", field:"date", formatter:dateFormatter}
```

Comment: Got it to work with a simple change  input.setAttribute("type", "date"); to  input.setAttribute("type", "datetime-local");

Thank you Oli.